# Gitlab CI job works fine but always crashes with exit code 1

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, static-analysis

I', trying to lint dockerfiles using hadolint in Gitlab CI with this snippet from my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
lint-dockerfile:
  image: hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian
  stage: verify
  script:
    - mkdir -p reports
    - hadolint -f gitlab_codeclimate Dockerfile > reports/hadolint-$(md5sum Dockerfile | cut -d" " -f1).json
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_JOB_NAME artifacts from $CI_PROJECT_NAME on $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"
    expire_in: 1 day
    when: always
    reports:
      codequality:
        - "reports/*"
    paths:
      - "reports/*"
```

This used to work perfectly fine but one week ago (without any change on my part) my pipeline started to crash all the time with `ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1`.

Full log output from job:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 14.0.0-rc1 (19d2d239)
  on docker-auto-scale 72989761
  feature flags: FF_SKIP_DOCKER_MACHINE_PROVISION_ON_CREATION_FAILURE:true
Resolving secrets 00:00
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 00:14
Using Docker executor with image hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian ...
Pulling docker image hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian ...
Using docker image sha256:7caf5ee484b575ecd32219eb6f2a7a114180c41f4d8671c1f8e8d579b53d9f18 for hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian with digest hadolint/hadolint@sha256:2c06786c0d389715dae465c9556582ed6b1c38e1312b9a6926e7916dc4a9c89e ...
Preparing environment 00:01
Running on runner-72989761-project-26715289-concurrent-0 via runner-72989761-srm-1624273099-5f23871c...
Getting source from Git repository 00:02
$ eval "$CI_PRE_CLONE_SCRIPT"
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Initialized empty Git repository in /builds/sommerfeld.sebastian/docker-vagrant/.git/
Created fresh repository.
Checking out f664890e as master...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script 00:01
Using docker image sha256:7caf5ee484b575ecd32219eb6f2a7a114180c41f4d8671c1f8e8d579b53d9f18 for hadolint/hadolint:latest-debian with digest hadolint/hadolint@sha256:2c06786c0d389715dae465c9556582ed6b1c38e1312b9a6926e7916dc4a9c89e ...
$ mkdir -p reports
$ hadolint -f gitlab_codeclimate Dockerfile > reports/hadolint-$(md5sum Dockerfile | cut -d" " -f1).json
Uploading artifacts for failed job 00:03
Uploading artifacts...
reports/*: found 1 matching files and directories  
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... ok  id=1363188460 responseStatus=201 Created token=vNM5xQ1Z
Uploading artifacts...
reports/*: found 1 matching files and directories  
Uploading artifacts as "codequality" to coordinator... ok  id=1363188460 responseStatus=201 Created token=vNM5xQ1Z
Cleaning up file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I have no idea why my build breaks all of a sudden. I'm using `image: docker:stable` as image for my whole .gitlab-ci.ymnl file.

Anywone got an idea?

Comment: It appears your hadolint command exits with an error code. Providing the log output might give an insight.

Comment: Where do I get the log output? All I see is the output from above. If you liek to take a look into the pipeline yourself, just see https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/docker-vagrant/-/pipelines.

Comment: It is saved under the job artifacts of the pipeline. which you can find [here](https://gitlab.com/sommerfeld.sebastian/docker-vagrant/-/pipelines) on the right burger menu of the pipeline. The job appears to run correctly as it warns you about: "multiple consecutive `run` instructions. consider consolidation." :) tl;dr your job is running perfectly fine as it fails when the lint job finds something of note.

Comment: But the lint job does not find anything of note ... the only file inside the artifacts-zip-file (hadolint-1c5b7593d165297d26f09a5bd302248d.json) contains only one line: `[{"location":{"path":"Dockerfile","lines":{"begin":8,"end":8}},"fingerprint":"c6bb25ce71517bde7afe36344fcfbe1ba83c2def","severity":"info","check_name":"DL3059","categories":["Bug Risk"],"type":"issue","description":"Multiple consecutive RUN instructions. Consider consolidation."}]` ... to me this looks like the same message as "multiple consecutive run instructions. consider consolidation." ...

Comment: Since you are using the latest tag of the hadolint image which was updated [recently](https://hub.docker.com/r/hadolint/hadolint/tags?page=1&ordering=last_updated) i guess that changed something. But i still think it's recommended behavior for a lint job to fail if it finds a flaw such as the one you mentioned above (DL3059). If you don't want your pipeline failing you may add `|| true` behind the hadolint command.

Comment: This is it ... I did not think of the image being updated. And I did not expect that a finding which is marked an Info only caused the build to break. But this was the case actually. I removed the duplicate RUN and the job is successful again. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To conclude this question. The issue was an unexpected change in behavior probably caused by an update of the **hadolint** image used here.

The job was in fact failing because the linter decided to do so. For anyone wanting the job to succeed anyway here is a little trick:

`hadolint -f gitlab_codeclimate Dockerfile > reports/hadolint-$(md5sum Dockerfile | cut -d" " -f1).json || true`

Given command will force the exit code to be positive no matter what happens.

Another option as @Sebastian Sommerfeld pointed out is to use [allow_failure: true](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#allow_failure) which essentially allows the script to fail, which will then be marked in the pipeline overview. Only drawback to this approach is that script execution is interrupted at the point of failure and no further commands may be executed.

Comment: That is more like a workaround than a solution.

Comment: Given that the job failing is the intended outcome this is in fact a work around for those who need it to not fail but still do the linting job.

Comment: In case the job should not break the build, it might be better to add `allow_failure: true` to the job in your .gitlab-ci.yml. This way the job would fail and would be marked as failed in the UI but the build does not break. When returning true the job would always be marked successful even if linter returns errors. Using `allow_failure: true` is more obvious to the eye.